# "dotnet ef database update" Fails (foreign key constraint fails)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I want to seed my Products table with some initial data using `dotnet ef migrations add Seed` (successful) then `dotnet ef update database` (failed).

`dotnet ef update database` output:

```
...
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (139ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO `Products` (`Id`, `CategoryId`, `Name`, `QuantityInPackage`, `UnitOfMeasurement`)
      VALUES (100, 100, 'Apple', 1, 1);
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`SupermarketDB`.`Products`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Products_Categories_CategoryId` FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryId`) REFERENCES `Categories` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`SupermarketDB`.`Products`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Products_Categories_CategoryId` FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryId`) REFERENCES `Categories` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
.
.
.
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`SupermarketDB`.`Products`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Products_Categories_CategoryId` FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryId`) REFERENCES `Categories` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

From my understanding, It basically says that I want to associate a data with something that doesn't exist which is not true.
Then I tried to insert it directly via mysql cli by copy-pasting the query from the error message, it worked.

Why I'm unable to achieve this via `dotnet ef ...`? How to do it properly?

---

```
$ dotnet --version
2.2.202

$ dotnet ef --version
Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools
2.2.3-servicing-35854
```

Table "Categories"

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name  | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
+-----+--------------------+
| Id  | Name               |
+-----+--------------------+
| 100 | Fruits and Veggies |
| 101 | Dairy              |
| 102 | Bakery             |
| 104 | Sweets             |
+-----+--------------------+
```

Table "Products"

```
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id                | int(11)             | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name              | varchar(50)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| QuantityInPackage | smallint(6)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| UnitOfMeasurement | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| CategoryId        | int(11)             | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
empty
```

AppDbContext.cs

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<Category>().ToTable("Categories");
            builder.Entity<Category>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
            builder.Entity<Category>().Property(p => p.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            builder.Entity<Category>().Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(30);
            builder.Entity<Category>().HasMany(p => p.Products).WithOne(p => p.Category).HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId);

            builder.Entity<Category>().HasData(
                new Category { Id = 100, Name = "Fruits and Veggies" },
                new Category { Id = 101, Name = "Dairy" }
            );

            builder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("Products");
            builder.Entity<Product>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
            builder.Entity<Product>().Property(p => p.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            builder.Entity<Product>().Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
            builder.Entity<Product>().Property(p => p.QuantityInPackage).IsRequired();
            builder.Entity<Product>().Property(p => p.UnitOfMeasurement).IsRequired();

            builder.Entity<Product>().HasData(
                new Product {
                    Id = 100,
                    Name = "Apple",
                    QuantityInPackage = 1,
                    UnitOfMeasurement = EUnitOfMeasurement.Unity,
                    CategoryId = 100
                },
                new Product {
                    Id = 101,
                    Name = "Emmental Cheese",
                    QuantityInPackage = 150,
                    UnitOfMeasurement = EUnitOfMeasurement.Gram,
                    CategoryId = 101
                }
            );
        }
```

Complete `dotnet ef update database` output:

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.2.4-servicing-10062 initialized 'AppDbContext' using provider 'Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql' with options: None
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (68ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='SupermarketDB' AND TABLE_NAME='__EFMigrationsHistory';
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='SupermarketDB' AND TABLE_NAME='__EFMigrationsHistory';
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT `MigrationId`, `ProductVersion`
      FROM `__EFMigrationsHistory`
      ORDER BY `MigrationId`;
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20402]
      Applying migration '20190604143215_AddSeeds'.
Applying migration '20190604143215_AddSeeds'.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      DELETE FROM `Categories`
      WHERE `Id` = 100;
      SELECT ROW_COUNT();
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      DELETE FROM `Categories`
      WHERE `Id` = 101;
      SELECT ROW_COUNT();
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (139ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO `Products` (`Id`, `CategoryId`, `Name`, `QuantityInPackage`, `UnitOfMeasurement`)
      VALUES (100, 100, 'Apple', 1, 1);
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`SupermarketDB`.`Products`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Products_Categories_CategoryId` FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryId`) REFERENCES `Categories` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`SupermarketDB`.`Products`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Products_Categories_CategoryId` FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryId`) REFERENCES `Categories` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ResultSet.cs:line 43
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 81
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ReadFirstResultSetAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 307
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(MySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, ResultSetProtocol resultSetProtocol, IOBehavior ioBehavior) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 292
   at MySqlConnector.Core.TextCommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(String commandText, MySqlParameterCollection parameterCollection, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\TextCommandExecutor.cs:line 37
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlCommand.cs:line 276
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlCommand.cs:line 77
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
Failed executing DbCommand (139ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
INSERT INTO `Products` (`Id`, `CategoryId`, `Name`, `QuantityInPackage`, `UnitOfMeasurement`)
VALUES (100, 100, 'Apple', 1, 1);
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`SupermarketDB`.`Products`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Products_Categories_CategoryId` FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryId`) REFERENCES `Categories` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`SupermarketDB`.`Products`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Products_Categories_CategoryId` FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryId`) REFERENCES `Categories` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ResultSet.cs:line 43
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 81
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ReadFirstResultSetAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 307
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(MySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, ResultSetProtocol resultSetProtocol, IOBehavior ioBehavior) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 292
   at MySqlConnector.Core.TextCommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(String commandText, MySqlParameterCollection parameterCollection, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\TextCommandExecutor.cs:line 37
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlCommand.cs:line 276
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlCommand.cs:line 77
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`SupermarketDB`.`Products`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Products_Categories_CategoryId` FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryId`) REFERENCES `Categories` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Comment: After checking the output, it contains `DELETE FROM `Categories`
      WHERE `Id` = 100;`, have you modifed the generated migrations? Fail to reproduce your issue with your code, share us a mini demo which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: @TaoZhou I see. I'm pretty new to EF, so I was careless and I didn't double-check the generated migrations. I don't understand why it deletes the initial seeds. Basically, the initial migrations has only "Categories" table and its seeds, then I generate for "Products" table after. Is that the cause?

Comment: You could add `Categories` and `Products` class together, and then run add migrations and update database.